# Trying to install PyGreSQL, receiving DLL load failed error

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I am trying to install the PyGreSQL package into Python 2.7.  I am running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.  The installer I am using is the file PyGreSQL-4.1.1.win32-py2.7.exe from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGreSQL/).

The installation of PyGreSQL purportedly proceeds successfully, but upon attempting to import the module in python, with

```
import pg
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "pg.py", line 31, in <module>
        from _pg import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

My PostgreSQL installation is 64-bit, if that complicates things.  Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The correct download path is from the Python Package Index (PyPi) [PyGreSQL-4.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGreSQL/)

Comment: The DLL load error is what you see if you try to load a 32-bit package from 64-bit Python (or vice versa). Check again with `import platform; print(platform.architecture()[0])`.

Comment: @MikeT 32 bit it says.